# How to start an animation when GUI button in press

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created simple animation in .fbx in blender and import it into the unity. The animation name is simple_anim and the animation will work fine when i play the button. But now i have added two GUI button and i want when i press gui button then the animation will run..I am new to script and i have written this simple script but its not working fine.

```
function onGUI() 
{ 
  if(GUI.Button(Rect(10,10,150,100),"Button")) 
   {
    animation.play("simple_anim"); 
   }
 }
```

But its not working fine.....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear to me, but I've got two things to say about it:

1. When using the Play-function, the P should be capitalized. So it should be:

   animation.Play("simple_anim");

   See: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html
2. You say you have two buttons. In that case, you might want to have the effect that when you click on the one button, the other stops animating. In that case, your code should be:

   animation.Play("simple_anim", PlayMode.StopAll);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, It might not be the easyest way around. But should work.

```
 var animation_bool : boolean ;

    function Update()
    {
     if(animation_bool == true)
      {
        animation.Play("slash");
      }
    }

   function onGUI() 
   { 
    if(GUI.Button(Rect(10,10,150,100),"Button")) 
     {
      animation_bool = true;
     }
   }
```